# cycle through the rest of Enumerator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, for-loop, iterator, enumerator

I have an Enumerator in the middle of some sequence:

```
enum = (1..9).each
first = enum.next
second = enum.next
```

Now I want to cycle through the rest of the sequence (3..9 numbers). But seeming obvious solution (which works in python, e.g.), restart from the beginning of the sequence instead of the third item:

```
for item in enum
    puts item
end
# prints 1..9 instead of 3..9
```

Working solution which I found seems ugly:

```
begin
    while item=enum.next
        puts item
    end
rescue StopIteration
end
```

So the question: is there a nicer rubyish solution to do this thing? And why does `for` loop in Ruby act this way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your question directly, your current code is on the right lines but over-engineered. You only need to do:

```
enum = (1..9).each
first = enum.next
second = enum.next

loop { puts enum.next }
```

The loop will `break` as soon as the enum reaches its end; the `loop` automatically rescues `StopIteration` for you. It will only be re-raised if you call `enum.next` **again**, after the loop, which doesn't happen here.

However as pointed out by @mudasobwa, using enums like this quite ususual; more common would be to use `(1..9).each_with_index` and explicitly handle the first yields by their index.

Comment: Wow, indeed, `rescue` is redundant, thanks, never knew that (which in turn means the whole construct is as unrubyish that I failed to try it in 5+ years experience :)

Comment: @mudasobwa [From the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/StopIteration.html): *"`StopIteration` - Raised to stop the iteration, in particular by `Enumerator#next`. It is rescued by `Kernel#loop`."* But yes, I had to double-check too, despite having a similar amount of experience; it's very rare to see `enum.next` in ruby code!

Comment: Don't undervalue `enum.next`! One example: `n.public_send(enum.next, m)`, where `enum = [:+, :- ].cycle`.

Answer (score 3):

In ruby you are strongly encouraged not to use `for`, `while` and `until` unless you do perfectly know what and why you are doing.

I could hardly imagine the real problem when one needs to do something *special* on first two elements of `Enumerable` (this possibly means an architectural issue,) but instead of this:

```
enum.next
enum.next
loop do
  begin
    puts enum.next
  rescue StopIteration
    break 
  end
end
```

*Update:* `rescue` is not needed there, see @TomLord’s answer for clarification.

You’d better do this:

```
enum.with_index do |element, idx|
  print "First " if idx == 0
  print "Second " if idx == 1
  puts element
end
```

`Iterator`’s internals almost never should be called explicitly, use efficient and idiomatic iteration, mapping and reducing instead.

Comment: `with_index` is in class `Enumerator`, If so, why `enum.each.with_index` why not `enum.with_index` ?

Comment: @Rajagopalan to trigger the iteration. `enum.with_index` returns an enumerator.

Comment: `p enum.each.with_index.class` returns enumerator as well.

Comment: @Rajagopalan ah, indeed, you are certainly right, thanks. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, case is important: `"enum.each.with_index.class"` returns the class `Enumerator`, not an "enumerator". Also, `p` at the beginning prints `"Enumerator"`as opposed to returning `Enumerator`.  Be precise!

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, I did not understand you. both are returning the object of enumerator class, eh?